# Google Documents List API file upload 400 response

Tags: java, google-docs-api, apache-httpclient-4.x

I am writing my own implementation of the Google Drive client for the Android and I am using the docs list api. Recently I've encountered a following problem:

At first I was using the HttpURLConnection to upload the file but it seems like it writes the data to the socket after a call to getResponseCose(), not when I am writing to the connection's OutputStream, which is a must for me.
Then I've switched to the Apache HttpClient but I'm still getting a 400 response, not sure why. Maybe you will be able to help me. Here is the code used to upload a file.

```
String putUrl = conn.getHeaderField("Location");//from the previous request
final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
final HttpPut put = new HttpPut(putUrl);

MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
put.addHeader("Content-Type", mime==null?"file":mime);
//put.addHeader("Content-Length", String.valueOf(length));
put.addHeader("Content-Range", "bytes 0-"+(length-1)+"/"+length);
put.addHeader("GData-Version", "3.0");
put.addHeader("Authorization", getAuthorizationProperty());
entity.addPart("content", new InputStreamBody(in, name));
put.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse resp = client.execute(put);
int response = resp.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
if(response == HttpStatus.SC_CREATED){
    lastCreated = parseSingleXMLEntry(resp.getEntity().getContent());
}
```

Exactly the same headers worked for HttpURLConnection. Maybe the entity is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the solution is quite simple, hope it will be useful for someone.

I had to delete all lines which added headers to the request. After that I've added the mime type to the InputStreamBody constructor and overriden the getContentLength() method to provide stream length. Finally it looks like this:

```
MultipartEntity entity = new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
entity.addPart("content", new InputStreamBody(in, ,mime, name){
     @Override
     public long getContentLength() {
          return length;
     }
});
put.setEntity(entity);

HttpResponse resp = client.execute(put);
```

And that's all.